# WCF: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8733/'

Tags: c#, wcf

Просле добавления serviceAuthorization net.tcp binding не работает. При добавлении Service Reverence выдает ошибку: **WCF: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8733/'.**

Config файл:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="ChartServices.Service.ChartManagerService">
         <endpoint address="ChartServices" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsBindingConfig" name="wsBinding_UserService" contract="ChartServices.Services_Contract.IUserService" />
         <endpoint address="ChartServices" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig" name="netTcp_UserService" contract="ChartServices.Services_Contract.IUserService" />
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="mexTcp" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexHttp" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8733/" />
               <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8734/" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
      </service>
   </services>
   <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="wsBindingConfig">
            <security mode="Message">
               <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
            </security>
         </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
         <binding name="netTcpBindingConfig">
            <security mode="Message">
               <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
            </security>
         </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="mexBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <serviceCredentials>
               <clientCertificate>
                  <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
               </clientCertificate>
               <serviceCertificate findValue="RootCATest" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" />
               <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ChartServices.CustomUserNameValidator, ChartServices" />
            </serviceCredentials>
            <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="ChartServices.MyServiceAuthorizationManager, ChartServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
               <authorizationPolicies>
                  <add policyType="ChartServices.AuthorizationPolicy, ChartServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
               </authorizationPolicies>
            </serviceAuthorization>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема. Без serviceAuthorization все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял это проблема Visual Studio 2017
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1741